# OpenGL Window Overlay

Tags: opengl, overlay

What I need to do is create a program that overlays the whole screen and every 30 seconds the screen needs to flash black once.

the program just needs to be on top of everything, doesn't have to work over the top of games, but wouldn't say no if it did!

But i've got no idea where to start. Ideally the solution would be cross-platform for both windows and osx.

Does anybody have any ideas about where I should start or could whip up a quick demo?

Answer (score 0):

OpenGL (you tagged it as such) will not help you with this.

> Create a program, that overlays the whole screen,

The canonical way to do this is by creating a decorationless, borderless top level window with some stay-on-top property being set.

> and every 30 seconds the screen needs to flash black once.

How do you define "flash back once"? You mean you want the display become visible for one single vertical retrace period or a given amount of time? Being the electronics tinkerer I am, honestly, I'd do this using a handfull of transistors, resistors and capacitors, blanking the analog VGA signal.

Anyway, if you want to do this using software, this is going to be hard work. If you'd do this using the aforementioned stay-on-top window, when you "flash" it away, all the programs with visible output would receive redraw events, which to process would take some time. In the best case scenario the system uses a compositing window manager which can practically immediately show the desktop. Without a compositor its going to be impossible to "flash" the screen.

> Ideally the solution would be cross-platform for both windows and osx

A task like this can not be solved cross plattform. There's too much OS dependent work to do for this.

I presume this is for some kind of nerological or psychological experiment. I think doing this using some VGA intercepting circurity would be actually the easier, quicker to implement solution. I can help you with that. But I think there's another StackExchange better suited for this. Unfortunately digital display interfaces (DVI, HDMI and Display Port) use a complex line code scheme, which can not be blanked as easily as VGA, so you must have a computer capable of analog (=VGA) output and a display with a VGA input.

Comment: I immediately thought about that "bubbles" screen saver introduced in Vista.

Comment: Ive just managed to do the overlay thats completely transparent, however you cannot click through it yet. I was thinking, would it be possible to maybe just toggle between like, background-color: transparent; and background-color: black; do that every 30 seconds? would that be a suitable method?

I'm currently trying this in visual studio express as a WPF Application, struggling to get the main window to have an image constantly up with a transparent bg though.